# Declare an arrow function as return in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, meteor, return-value, arrow-functions

I want to write a TypeScript Declaration for [ReactMeteorData.jsx](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/blob/devel/packages/react-meteor-data/ReactMeteorData.jsx) which exports:

```
export default function connect(options) {
  let expandedOptions = options;
  if (typeof options === 'function') {
    expandedOptions = {
      getMeteorData: options,
    };
  }

  const { getMeteorData, pure = true } = expandedOptions;

  const BaseComponent = pure ? ReactPureComponent : ReactComponent;
  return (WrappedComponent) => (
    class ReactMeteorDataComponent extends BaseComponent {
      ...
    }
  );
}
```

Which is repacked as withTracker by [react-meteor-data.jsx](https://github.com/meteor/react-packages/blob/devel/packages/react-meteor-data/react-meteor-data.jsx):

```
export { default as withTracker } from './ReactMeteorData.jsx';
```

I can simply declare the return value as Function:

```
declare module 'meteor/react-meteor-data' {
  import * as React from 'react';    
  export function withTracker(func: () => {}): Function;

  ...
}
```

How can I declare what arguments and returns the Function creates without the need to change something in the origin package? So I would like to do something like:

```
export function withTracker(func: () => {}): (React.Component) => { React.Component };
```

Usage of the code is like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data';

class Header extends React.Component<any,any> {
  render() {
    return "test";
  }
}

export default withTracker(() => {
  return { user: 1 };
})(Header);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type you describe could be written like this:

```
(c: React.Component) => React.Component
```

In the section `declare module`:

```
export function withTracker(func: () => {}): (c: React.Component) => React.Component;
```

Comment: So easy! Thank you!